# Abstract information for data that movies through different stages

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to generate multiple bar charts for users that transition through different stages. Following is my structure for **user_stage_mappings** table

```
+----+----------+---------+------------------+----------------+
| id | stage_id | user_id | stage_start_date | stage_end_date |
+----+----------+---------+------------------+----------------+
|  1 |        1 |       1 | 2017-12-25       | 2018-01-02     |
|  2 |        2 |       1 | 2018-01-02       | 2018-01-05     |
|  3 |        3 |       1 | 2018-02-05       |                |
+----+----------+---------+------------------+----------------+
```

Now I would like to plot 3 individual charts for each stage, starting from **1st Jan 2018** to **7th Jan 2018** (dates can be any range). So the charts would appear something as follows.

**Stage 1 Chart :**
Show bar with 1 count for **1st** and **2nd** Jan, as the idea was in Stage 1 during those days, and no bars for the rest of the days.

**Stage 2 Chart :**
Show bar with 1 count for **2nd** to **5th** Jan, as the idea was in Stage 2 during those days, and no bars for 1st, 6th & 7th Jan.

**Stage 3 Chart :**
Show bar with 1 count for **5th** to **7th** Jan, as the idea was in Stage 3 during those days, Note there is no end date to the last stage indicating the idea is still in Stage 3.

I have reduced the dataset to bare minimum, the actual dataset would have several users at different stages. What would be the most optimal way to write this as mysql query.

I was thinking maybe loop through 1st to the 7th of Jan and with each iteration count the number of users. For example for the 1st of Jan get users where 1st Jan is between stage_start_date and stage_end_date, but somehow this does not feel optimal.

Answer (score 0):

To me it will be easier to just plot the charts via looping. I explain, first get the number of users for each day with:

```
SELECT DATE(stage_start_date) stage_start_date, count(DISTINCT user_id) NoOfUsers
FROM user_stage_mappings
WHERE stage_start_date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2018-01-01','%Y-%m-%d')
AND STR_TO_DATE('2018-01-07','%Y-%m-%d')
GROUP BY DATE(stage_start_date)
ORDER BY DATE(stage_start_date);
```

This data can be fetch by the application layer of your dashboard, and stored in an array. You can now fetch the different stage chart data by just manipilating the array based on the index.
Trying to get the complete expected information directly from the database would be a pain in the ass.